# Solving the Pell's equation $x^2-11y^2=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

> Solving Pell equation using general Pell equation

Now I have to find a solution of $x^2-11y^2=1$ and I know that $\pm(3,1)$ is a solution for $x^2-11y^2=-2$. If I apply Brahmagupta's composition rule [here](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/nti/chap5.pdf#page=4) I obtain a solution $(20,6)$ for $x^2-11y^2=4$, and I noticed that the solution $(x,y)$ of the latter equation has even $x$ and $y$ (also for $x^2-19y^2=4$), so if I divide $x$ and $y$ by $2$ then I get a solution of the Pell equation, so the question is, Is the following statement correct ?

If $x^2-Dy^2=-2$ is solvable then one can always find with Brahmagupta's method a solution of the Pell equation.

Comment: Have you seen this book: http://djm.cc/library/Algebra_Elementary_Text-Book_Part_II_Chrystal_edited02.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: if $x^2 - D y^2 = -2$, then $u = (x^2 + D y^2)/2 = D y^2 - 1$ and $v = x y$ satisfy $u^2 - D v^2 = 1$.